# UITabBarController created in Interface Builder - 'More' and 'Edit' re-ordering of tabs doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a UITabBarController configured in Interface Builder as my main application interface.  It has seven tabs, which triggers the "More" functionality of UITabBarController.  When you select the "More" view, you get the "Edit" button as well, allowing the user to configure the order of the tabs.  However, when you click "Edit", I can't actually reorder the tabs; dragging the icons around doesn't seem to have an affect.

Should this work?  Is this a by-product of using Interface Builder to configure my UITabBarController, as opposed to building it programmatically?

Just to note, I see all of my tabs in the 'Edit' re-order panel and they are all contained in 'customizableViewControllers' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are unfamiliar with the reordering mechanism.  Make sure that you are dragging items around from the top area to the tab bar itself, not merely attempting to reorder them in the top area.